Router in router
I'm doing a project using Cookiecutter Django. I have urls and api_router.py in config. I want to add another url in 'api/' but I can't do that. I want to see the url in 'api/' like:
{
    "users": "http://localhost:8000/api/users/"
}

I tried use registry but doesn't work.
I have api_router.py:
router = DefaultRouter() if settings.DEBUG else SimpleRouter()

router.register("users", UserViewSet)
router.registry.extend(product_router.registry)
print(router.registry)

app_name = "api"
urlpatterns = router.urls

and products/urls.py:
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('products', ProductViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]

and then, in the main urls:
# API URLS
urlpatterns += [
    # API base url
    path("api/", include("config.api_router")),
    # DRF auth token
    path("auth-token/", obtain_auth_token),
    path("api/schema/", SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name="api-schema"),
    path(
        "api/docs/",
        SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name="api-schema"),
        name="api-docs",
    ),
]

When I print router.registry:
[('users', <class 'panasystem.users.api.views.UserViewSet'>, 'user'), ('products', <class 'panasystem.products.views.products.ProductViewSet'>, 'product')]

So, I want to have different endpoints in localhost:8000/api/.
